# Difference between x(1) and x{1}

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, cell

```
>> x = {  {'a',[1],[2]};  {'b',[3],[4]}  }
x =    
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}

>> A1 = x(1)    
A1 =     
    {1x3 cell}

>> A2 = x{1}   
A2 =    
    'a'    [1]    [2]
```

Note that `A1` and `A2` display differently.

`A1` and `A2` report as being the same class and dimension:

```
>> info = @(x){class(x),size(x)};
>> info(A1)     
ans =    
    'cell'    [1x2 double]

>> info(A2)     
ans =     
    'cell'    [1x2 double]
```

yet they and are not considered equal:

```
>> isequal( A1, A2 )    
ans =    
     0
```

However, `A1{:}` *is* considered as being equal to `A2`:

```
>> isequal( A1{:}, A2 )    
ans =    
     1
```

Could someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Is this not covered by [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/235/introduction-to-matlab/3038/cell-arrays#t=201610201316213508443)?

Comment: The title is as I intended. `x[]` access is illegal.

Comment: It's not "illegal".  It is undefined.

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted if it worked for you (and leaving some comments if none of them did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `x` is a *cell* containing 2 (sub)*cells*.

1. Curly brackes is used to get the content of a cell, thus,

   ```
   A2 = x{1}
   ans = 
      'a'    [1]    [2]
   ```

   Which gives the same result as

   ```
   A2 = {'a',[1],[2]}
   ```
2. Parentheses is used for indexing and therefore returns a **subset** of
   the (sub)cells

   ```
   A1 = x(1)    
   A1 =     
       {1x3 cell}
   ```

   Which gives the same result as

   ```
   A1 = { {'a',[1],[2]} }
   ```

Your anonymous info function returns a cell (needs to as the content is of mixed types). The result

```
'cell'    [1x2 double]
```

tells that both A1 and A2 is cells which is true, not considering the fact that  A1 is a cell containing cells and A2 is a cell containing a char and 2 numbers.

The `[1x2 double]` simply tells that the answer from size is itself of size [1x2]. This is true as long as you don't use higher dimensions than 2.

If you dig deeper into your `info` answer you will see the real size:

```
A1info = info(A1);
A2info = info(A2);
A1info{2}
ans =
     1     1
A2info{2}
ans =
     1     3
```

The part of `isequal( A1, A2 )` beeing `false` I think you understand by now.

Also, that `isequal( A1{:}, A2)` is true, since {:} "de-cell" `A1` and pick out its content.
In this case, you could have typed `isequal( A1{1}, A2)` as well

Answer (score 4):

`()` is used for function inputs and to index arrays; `[]` is used to denote arrays; `{}` is used to index cells.

```
A = [2 1]; % Creates and array A with elements 2 and 1
A(2) =2; % Sets the second element of A to 2
B = cell(1,2); % creates a cell array
B{2} = A; % Stores A in the second cell of B
```

So in conclusion: `x(1)` selects the first element of array `x` or evaluates the function `x` at `1`; `x[1]` should not be possible, as square brackets can't be used to index stuff; `x{1}` would select the first cell in cell array `x`.

As to your specific problem:

```
A1 = x(1); % makes a copy of the element on index one, being a 1x3 cell
A2 = x{1}; % stores the content of the cell at element 1 in A2
```

Finally `A1{:}` gets the content of the cell out of the cell, ready to store as a separate variable, hence it is equal to `A2`, which already contains that content. (`A1{:}` is a [comma separated list](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), thanks to [rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154345/difference-between-x1-and-x1/40154551?noredirect=1#comment67588793_40154551) for pointing that out.)

Comment: I'd like to point out that `A1{:}` outputs a comma-separated list. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html

Answer (score 2):

data{1} is to access the content of a cell
data(1) is to create a cell with a copy of the first entry of data. This is the same as :

```
>> A1=cell(1,1);
>> A1{1}=data{1};
```

In your example A1 is thus a cell containing a cell, while A2 is a cell with three entries

Comment: So I'm guessing that whenever MatLab's `ans` is a 1x1 cell, what is displayed is the *contents* of that cell. Neither answer so far as addressed why both forms display identically.

Comment: @Pi MATLAB display has little to do with the data type. Sometimes it will display the whole thing, sometimes just give you the size, depends on if its fits on screen